# How can I make my program get three specific letters

Tags: if-statement, random

I need help to make my random generator only produce three letters:G, R, B. How can I do this because the ASCII Code for B is 66, G is 71,and R is 82. I appreciate any help.
I tried starting it like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String color=color();
        System.out.println(color);
    }
    static String color(){
        String color=null;
        int randnum=(int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
        if(randnum==1){
            color= "B";
        }

        return color;
    }
}
```

But the thing I don't get is that it will also produce other numbers. I only want G, R, B as the random number to be outputed
.

Comment: What language is this? Javascript? C#?

Comment: My advice would be to store those letters in an array, then use a random number between 0 and 2 to get to a random index of that array, giving you a random letter in that 3 letters set

Comment: You could use modulo 3 and do your if on values between 0 and 2 also.

Comment: Why are you getting other numbers? Because letter=(int)(Math.random()*82)+66 will give you random number between 0 and 82. Then you add 66 so the resulting number is a random number between 66 and 148. That's a lot more numbers than you want.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to make it generate the exact numbers 66,71,and 82 if all you are doing is assigning letter via a random value. Just do (int)(Math.random()*3) and do something like:

```
if(letter==0){
    letter="B";
}
else if(letter==1){
    letter="G";
}
else if(letter==2){ 
    letter="R";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are more concise ways of doing it, to demonstrate the principle consider this:

```
letter=(int)(Math.random()*100)
if(letter < 33)
  letter="B";
else if(letter >= 33 && letter < 66)
  letter="G";
else
  letter="R";
```

If I were doing this in a non-trivial setting, though, and there were any chance I'd be needing to do it again with a different set of letters, I'd define a function to return a randomly selected element from an array, and pass in ['B', 'G', 'R']. You never said what language you're working in, so I hesitate to offer an example, but pass in the array and bound the random number on array.length.

Comment: `R` will occur more in the long run.

Comment: Marginally, yeah. `floor(Math.random() * 3)` would have been the more technically correct answer (or better yet, `floor(Math.random() * arr.length)`, with the letters all stuck in an array). I wanted an answer close to the original, though, so it was only introducing one new concept. I may have overdone it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
match random() % 3 with
| 0 -> B
| 1 -> R
| _ -> G
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on java this is the best way to represent the answer

just put the Red green blue in an array list and randomize it with random class

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("RED");

    list.add("GREEN");

    list.add("blue");

    String random = list.get(randomizer.nextInt(list.size()));`